# C++ TCHAR to char conversion

Tags: c++, windows

How do you convert a `TCHAR` to a `char` array without using built-in functions and with out including other header files (how do you do convert TCHAR to char using standard c++ )

```
int main()
{

    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = _T("<unknown>");
    char szText[MAX_PATH] ;

    std::cout << sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) << std::endl;


    for (int i =0; i <sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR); i++ )
    {
            szText[i] = (char)szProcessName[i];
    }
    //szText[sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR)] = '\0';

    std::cout << strlen(szText) << " " << strlen("<unknown>") <<std::endl;
    std::cout << szText <<  " <unknown>" <<std::endl;


    if (szText == "<unknown>") 
        std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << "Not equal " << std::endl;


    return 0; 
}
```

what i got in the console

```
$ g++ test.cpp && ./a.exe
260
9 9
<unknown> <unknown>
Not equal
```

Comment: `TCHAR` is not standard C++ anyway. It is Windows-specific.

Comment: Also, it is not clear what you mean with "_without using built-in functions and with out including other header files_" or why that is relevant. What do you consider built-in functions? Are you talking about standard library functions? Or maybe Windows API? What are the header files not counted under "other"?

Comment: You can't compare arrays for equality using `==` ...

Comment: @user17732522 I know that TCHAR is not a standard c++ and i mean using standard c++ functions like `sizeof` and i don't want to include any header files other than `iostream` and `tchar.h`

Comment: The first step is to know the encodings because `char` and `TCHAR` don't carry that info. If `TCHAR` is a narrow character, it should be encoded using the current code page, so that's already a multitude of source encodings to support. Then you need to know which encoding the result should be in because `char` could be conceivably used for any encoding. A non-trivial amount of work went into the conversion routines that the Windows API offers.

Comment: @user17732522 I didn't define `_UNICODE` so `szProcessName` should be a `char` is that right ?

Comment: @manuel I don't think that is defined manually. I don't know enough about Windows to answer that. Let someone else tell you. But you can just check that with `char* test = szProcessName;`. Either it will compile or it won't. But if you are already using `TCHAR`, then you probably want the code to be generic. Otherwise why not use `char` from the start?

Comment: @user17732522 i don't understand `TCHAR` yet but I am using an example from Microsoft docs and they used `TCHAR`

Comment: As a side note, if my other comment doesn't make much sense, it's quite possible that you shouldn't need to use `TCHAR` in the first place. `TCHAR` is there specifically so that the same source code can be compiled with or without wide character support and continue to work. If you don't need legacy support, the norm has _long_ been to use the wide versions of everything in the API and forget `TCHAR` exists. That gives you support for more than your own local set of extra characters and you don't need all the code to be awkwardly generic with strings for a build variant you'll never use.

Comment: @manuel If you are following a Microsoft example, why don't you want to use the appropriate conversion functions that Microsoft offers? It is not going to be standard C++ anyway. I have a feeling you could be helped much better if you gave context for what you are really trying to do.

Comment: That said, I have seen the choice go the other way lately, specifically to use UTF-8 with the narrow versions of the APIs (not with `TCHAR`, just making an explicit choice in the other direction). That is an option in the present day, but I've also heard some bad cases there around apps interacting with other apps. I don't have the personal experience to weigh in on that.

Comment: @user17732522 I am still in the process of learning, Microsoft docs is not 10 page book  and some concepts are really hard to learn on your own but anyway here is the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes)

Comment: @manuel - Assuming you haven't changed your compiler options, TCHAR will just be wchar_t which is UTF-16.  You should just use all the wide versions of the c++ APIs which will work with this.  E.g. `wcslen()` instead of `strlen`, `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout` etc.  Don't bother converting to char, almost all windows devs just work in wide characters anyway and use the c++ `std::wstring` type.

Comment: @manuel `if (szText == "<unknown>")` -- You do realize this isn't correct?  You do not compare C-style strings this way.

Comment: The type TCHAR is defined based on the encoding system you use.  The TCHAR can represent wide characters or it can represent ASCII characters.  If you compiled for TCHAR to be wide, then you'll lose some information when converting to type `char`.  You may still be able to search the MS header files to find out where TCHAR is defined.

Comment: `TCHAR` was a cunning solution to a problem of the late 1990s. Microsoft had two main lines of operating systems, the old 8-bit ANSI character-based Win9X line and the 16-bit Unicode-based Windows NT line, and people wanted to write programs that compiled and ran easily on both platforms. Depending on the compiler options used, `TCHAR` would resolve to the correct character type. This stopped being a problem in the early 2000s as the Windows NT-based Windows XP crushed all comers. My modern advice is to not use `TCHAR` and instead use wide characters all the way through unless you need `TCHAR`

Comment: The reason you find `TCHAR` in all the Microsoft examples is that they had to keep it generic because they didn't know who would be reading it.

Comment: So, just decide on either `char` or `wchar_t` and use that instead. Skip `TCHAR` and **everyting else** from `tchar.h`. It was outdated 25 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote my own function to compare two `char` arrays

```
int cmpstrs( char *x , char* y )
{

    if (strlen(x) != strlen(y) )
        return 0;

    for (int i =0; i < strlen(x); i++ )
    {
        if (x[i] != y[i])
            return 0;
    }   
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: There is already `strcmp` for this. Also, this doesn't actually answer the question you asked. The conversion is still broken if `TCHAR` is not `char` already.

Comment: @user17732522 i know but this seemed to fix my issue it is ugly and a copy of `strcmp` but this is what i managed to come up with

Comment: @manuel Ugly or low quality answers are at risk of being downvoted.  To compare two char arrays that are null-terminated, `strcmp` is used.  Your version also unnecessarily calls `strlen` twice on the same buffer, and is called repeatedly in the `for` loop syntax to denote loop continuance.

Comment: You can't use `strlen` with TCHAR because if TCHAR is wide, it is incompatible with standard `strlen`, which uses narrow or ASCII encodings.

Comment: You can simplify if you use `(*x != '\0') && (`*y != '\0') && (*x == *y)` as a continuation condition.